# USB port not connecting to or reading USB flash drives

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I am working on a desktop running Debian Stable Linux and it is otherwise working very well. Only problem is that it is not connecting to  USB flash drives. This is true for all its USB ports and I have tried with different USB flash drives.

On checking with command `sudo dmesg`, following error is seen:

```
[ 2320.803889] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[ 2320.883886] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 2321.279887] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 2321.675887] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 2321.755884] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 2322.567890] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 2322.676004] usb 2-1-port1: attempt power cycle
[ 2323.487893] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[ 2323.903890] usb 2-1.1: device not accepting address 5, error -32
[ 2323.983888] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[ 2324.399889] usb 2-1.1: device not accepting address 6, error -32
[ 2324.400122] usb 2-1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 2325.287888] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[ 2325.579891] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 2325.975888] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 2326.163888] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[ 2326.243887] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 2326.431897] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 2326.540084] usb 2-1-port1: attempt power cycle
[ 2327.143890] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[ 2327.559886] usb 2-1.1: device not accepting address 9, error -32
[ 2327.847887] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[ 2328.263883] usb 2-1.1: device not accepting address 10, error -32
[ 2328.264000] usb 2-1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 2328.499896] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[ 2329.455876] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 2329.651890] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 2329.843891] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
[ 2329.923873] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 2330.319890] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 2330.427998] usb 2-1-port1: attempt power cycle
```

Similar problem and messages are there with other USB ports, only port numbers are different:

```
[ 2509.740036] usb 2-1-port2: attempt power cycle
[ 2510.343900] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 53 using ehci-pci
[ 2510.759998] usb 2-1.2: device not accepting address 53, error -32
[ 2511.047899] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 54 using ehci-pci
[ 2511.463897] usb 2-1.2: device not accepting address 54, error -32
[ 2511.464007] usb 2-1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 2511.687897] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 55 using ehci-pci
[ 2511.975900] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 2512.163896] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 2512.351897] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 56 using ehci-pci
[ 2512.431896] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 2512.623896] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 2512.731975] usb 2-1-port2: attempt power cycle
[ 2513.335903] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 57 using ehci-pci
[ 2513.751895] usb 2-1.2: device not accepting address 57, error -32
[ 2514.039898] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 58 using ehci-pci
[ 2514.455916] usb 2-1.2: device not accepting address 58, error -32
[ 2514.456083] usb 2-1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: It's good that you've included dmesg - it shows that you've put effort into figuring it out yourself. But please [don't post text as images](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). You can use the [Edit] button to improve it.

Comment: Old but the suggestions there are still mostly valid: https://askubuntu.com/questions/7704/unable-to-enumerate-usb-device